# How to make match return results for multiple occurrences?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have all the source of webpage in a variable.Now i want to parse for something like this

```
<meta name="citation_author" content="Sabourin, J.L.">
```

What I am doing is this:

```
var res2 = data.match(/meta name="citation_author" .*">/);
                    console.log(res2[0]);
                    console.log(res2.length);
```

There are more than one tag which matches this but it only shows 1st answer and length = 1. I don't know why.

Comment: If you want all the matches, you have to append the "g" flag to the regex. `/meta name="citation_publisher" .*">/g`

Comment: Thanks a lot!!I am pretty naive in this!!